# python intellij warning by dictionary access, unexpected type

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pycharm

intellij idea is showing me a warning, what does this warning mean and how can I fix it?

Warning:

```
Unexpected type(s): (str) Possible type(s): (int | slice) (SupportsIndex) (slice)
```

Call:

```
example['val']['val_lvl1_4']['val_lvl1_4_1']
```

The access to the dictionary is working as expected, is this a bug?

Dictionary:

```
example = {
    'val': {
        'val_lvl1_1': 'link',
        'val_lvl1_5': 'val',
        'val_lvl1_6': 'default',
        'val_lvl1_7': 1000,
        'val_lvl1_8': 1,
        'val_lvl1_9': '',
        'val_lvl1_10': 7,
        'val_lvl1_11': [],
        'val_lvl1_12': False,
        'val_lvl1_2': 0,
        'val_lvl1_3': [],
        'val_lvl1_4': {
            'val_lvl1_4_1': {
                'val_lvl1_4_1_1': 'y',
                'val_lvl1_4_1_2': 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you include type hints when you constructed your dictionary?  And why aren't you using PyCharm instead of IntelliJ?  Same company, slicker python support...

Comment: i thought pycharm has the similar functions than IDEA Ultimate, how to add type hints?

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30676/False-positive-type-error-in-assignments-to-items-of-nested-lists-and-dicts